# Is overhead included in the download rate depiction of a download manager?

Tags: download, traffic, overhead

All the time when I download data (videos,files whatever) I notice that the rate I accumulate the necessary data to finish the file is lower than the downloading rate depicted by the downloadmanager.

Example if the download manager prints that I download at 3.5 MB/s I see only 2.5 MB increase per second of the actual file being downloaded ( visual example T0: 100MB, @ 3.5MB/s, T1: 102.5MB, @ 3.5MB/s, T2: 105MB. @ 3.5MB/s etc were T is time in seconds and each T increment is 1 second apart from the other -its not an ideal visualized example of what im talking about but its the best i can do in this post)

And I notice that difference (which every time is roughly the same -download increases ~2.5MB every second if download speed is ~3.5MB/s) using any download manager from browser default manager to third party.

So I wonder is overhead included when depicting the download rate ? Thus in my case 3.5MB/s means 2MB/s of actual usable data and 1MB/s overhead?

Because if thats true then isnt that a huge problem having such massive overhead? what should I check in order to address that problem?

If its not true then why is there a difference in displayed loaded data and data downloading rate?

Answer (score 0):

Overhead is included. Download manager would not have clue about which is overhead frame.

Comment: thats what I think as well but the thing that bugs me is that the difference is big (its like 40%+ overhead )

Comment: just for kicks I downloaded video - i didn't see any difference ..if you are downloading something from online - can you point to link ? - try below link http://www.clipconverter.cc/download/8ElObviO/132022677/ - i downloaded video from here

Comment: Are you sure you noticed the rate MB were added and the number designated to be your download speed? for this exact file I had 2.5 MB/s speed but the file was increasing like ~1.3 MB per second (some times lower)